# Is it possible to print path of the url in html without javascript and server side

Tags: javascript, html, nginx

I have a static html file at www.abc.com/def

Is it possible to print "def" inside html without using javascript. We cannot take server side help as it is a static html file.

Comment: You can write a script that generates these html files. Is this a valid approach?